# Getting serialized grandparent from ManyToMany relation DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm struggling to serialize the grandparent(s) of a ManyToMany relation in my models. In the product serializer, i want to list the top level `Category` based on the `SubCategory` selected on the `Product`. My code is structured like this:

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    
    ...
    name = models.CharField(
        _('category name'), 
        max_length=255, 
        unique=False
    )
    ...

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name='children', 
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        _('category name'), 
        max_length=255, 
        unique=False
    )
    ...

class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(
        _('product name'),
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
    )
    category = models.ManyToManyField(
        SubCategory,
        related_name='products'
    )
    ...
```

serializers.py

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['name']


class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...
    category = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True, many=True)
    parent_category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True, source='category.parent', many=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            ...
            'parent_category',
            'category',
            ...
        )
```

Currently the field parent_category does not show up in the json-response.

Edit:
serializers.py:

```
class ProductCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['name']

class ProductSubCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SubCategory
        fields = ['name']

class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...
    subcategory = ProductSubCategorySerializer(many=True, source='category')
    category = ProductCategorySerializer()
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            ...
            'category',
            'subcategory',
            ...
        )
```

Current output:

```
[
    {
        "subcategory": [
            {
                "name": "sub category name",
                "category": {
                    "name": "main category name"
                }
            },
        ],
    }
]
```

wished output:

```
[
    {
        "category": [
            {
                "name": "main category name"
            },
            ...
        ],
        "subcategory": [
            {
                "name": "sub category name",
            },
            ...
        ],
    }
]
```

Comment: Try to first link the `ProductsSerializer` to the `SubCategory` model creating a `serializer` for it - eg. in `ProductsSerializer`, get rid of `parent_category` and replace it with `subcategory = SubCategorySerializer(many=True)` - and once you have `SubCategorySerializer`, just set `category = CategorySerializer()`. Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help! I get `Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `subcategory` on serializer `ProductsSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Product` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Product' object has no attribute 'subcategory'.`. Look at the changed code in the edit of the post in case i've misunderstood you.

Comment: Hmm, can you try setting `source="category"` in `ProductsSerializer`s `subcategory`? If that doesn't work either, just use `category` instead of `subcategory`.

Comment: Setting the source worked for the subcategories, but the category field using the `ProductCategorySerializer()` returns `"category": {  "name": null },` in the response. Post once again updated.

Comment: Oh, ok, now you're just missing linking `ProductSubCategorySerializer` to `ProductCategorySerializer` by setting `category = ProductCategorySerializer(source="parent")` - by the way, you set this in **`ProductSubCategorySerializer`**. Don't forget to append it to `fields` as well!

Comment: Cheers. This however renders the parent inside the subcategory array. Is this the only way, or is it possible to add this as its own field in the reposne (`"category": {}`)? Current response: `"category": {  "name": null }, "subcategory": [{ "name": "subcategory name", "category": { "name": "category name" } }, ...`.

Comment: Use to_representaion function to customize the Output in product serializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full `serializers` setup would have to be like this:

```
class ProductCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['name']

class ProductSubCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = ProductCategorySerializer(source="parent")

    class Meta:
        model = SubCategory
        fields = ['name', 'category']

class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...
    subcategory = ProductSubCategorySerializer(many=True, source='category')
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            ...
            'subcategory',
            ...
        )
```

Comment: If you'd like another representation, let me know the details.

Comment: Sorry, should have made this clear upon posting. I've updated my post with current and wished output.

Comment: It seems like you want to dissociate subcategory from category creating an array for each; if you don't mind me asking, wouldn't that create some confusion? Like, you wouldn't know which subcategory belongs to which category.

Comment: You're completely right. I was overengineering in my head. Your answer is correct and marked thereafter.